# Finding the most common point of intersection among plotted triangles

Tags: matlab

I plotted a set of triangles using the code below:

```
A=[1, 1; 1, 5; 3, 9; 4, 2;9,9];
plot(A(:,1),A(:,2),'oc','LineWidth',2,'MarkerSize',5);
axis([0 10 0 10]);
grid on


for ii = 1:size(A, 1) - 1
    for jj = ii + 1:size(A, 1)
        line([A(ii, 1), A(jj, 1)], [A(ii, 2), A(jj, 2)])
    end
end
```

The problem is, i will like the plot to indicate the region with the highest number of intersections. In this particular code, the region is the black polygon (i had to indicate this region manually).

[image]

Please can anyone help out with this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a variant with a more *graphical* approach.

1. Create a grid of points
2. Check the number of triangles that a point
   is inside
3. Plot the points with highest number of intersecting
   triangles

The code

```
% Create the combination of all points that make the triangles
% This could be used to plot the lines as well
N = size(A,1);
comb = [];
for i = 1:N-2
    for j = i+1:N-1
        comb = [comb; repmat([i j], N-j,1) (j+1:N)']; %#ok<AGROW>
    end
end
nComb = size(comb,1);

% Create a mesh grid
dg = 0.1; % Resolution - tune this!
gridEdge = [min(A);max(A)];
[X, Y] = meshgrid(gridEdge(1,1):dg:gridEdge(2,1), gridEdge(1,2):dg:gridEdge(2,2));

% Check if a point is inside each triangle
[isInside, onEdge] = deal(zeros(numel(X),nComb));
for i = 1:nComb
   [isInside(:,i), onEdge(:,i)] = inpolygon(X(:),Y(:),A(comb(i,:),1),A(comb(i,:),2));
end
% Remove points on edge
isInside = isInside - onEdge; 

% Get index of points with most intersection
inTri = sum(isInside,2);
idx = find(inTri == max(inTri));

% Plot result
hold on
plot(X(idx),Y(idx),'.')
text(mean(X(idx)),mean(Y(:)),num2str(max(inTri)),'FontSize',20)
```

[image]